How to get how much sol was added to lp
Need to get how much sol and the token was added to lp with a signature when the token was created. Please provide a link to a project that has a solution, I am sure there are plenty. Using js would be ideal.

To get how much sol and the token was added to lp with a signature when the token was created you can use the Solana SPL token library and a project like the Solana Web3.js library.
You can find project examples below:

Example using Solana Web3.js => https://github.com/project-serum/serum-dex-ui/blob/master/src/utils/useMarket.tsx
Serum DEX JS Library => https://github.com/project-serum/serum-js

